# Lua examples to link to Asana

Tags: lua, asana

Do you have any Lua examples to access and change the Asana data. That will be really helpful. I want to link Asana to my offline task manager in Lua which provides me some additional flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

There are no Lua examples available in the documentation. If you have ever used Lua before to connect to a RESTful API, making HTTP requests to POST and GET, I expect the experience will be similar.